# Esta dando erro quando tento inserir no meu banco de sqlite + java

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

```
package Contas;


import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import BancoConexao.Banco;

public class ContaCorrente extends Conta{
    public ContaCorrente(int NumConta,String nome,float Saldo,String senha,int tipo) {
        super(NumConta, nome, Saldo, senha, tipo);
    }
    public void Cad() {
        Banco ContCorrente = new Banco();
        ContCorrente.conectar();
        String sql = "INSERT INTO ContaCliente("
                + "NumeroConta,"
                + "Nome,"
                + "Saldo,"
                + "Senha,"
                + "Tipo"
                + ") VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)"
                +";";

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Cadastrado!");
            PreparedStatement prepare = ContCorrente.criarPreparedStatement(sql);

            try{

               //aqui se encontra o erro, neste prepare
                prepare.setInt(1,getNumConta());
                prepare.setString(2,getNome());
                prepare.setFloat(3,getSaldo());
                prepare.setString(4,getSenha());
                prepare.setInt(5,getTipo());
                prepare.executeUpdate();
            }catch(SQLException e){
                System.out.println("Erro ao Cadastrar");
            }finally{
                if(prepare != null){
                    try {
                        prepare.close();
                    } catch (SQLException ex) {
                        System.out.println("Erro ao fechar o banco");
                    }
                }
            }
            ContCorrente.desconectar();
    }    
}
```

> ```
> java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: ContaCliente)
>   at org.sqlite.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:383)
>   at org.sqlite.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:387)
>   at org.sqlite.DB.throwex(DB.java:374)
>   at org.sqlite.NativeDB.prepare(Native Method)
>   at org.sqlite.DB.prepare(DB.java:123)
>   at org.sqlite.PrepStmt.<init>(PrepStmt.java:42)
>   at org.sqlite.Conn.prepareStatement(Conn.java:404)
>   at org.sqlite.Conn.prepareStatement(Conn.java:399)
>   at org.sqlite.Conn.prepareStatement(Conn.java:383)
>   at BancoConexao.Banco.criarPreparedStatement(Banco.java:54)
>   at Contas.ContaCorrente.Cad(ContaCorrente.java:27)
>   at Principal.main(Principal.java:32)
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at Contas.ContaCorrente.Cad(ContaCorrente.java:30)
>   at Principal.main(Principal.java:32)
> ```

esse é o erro q ta dando

Comment: *"está dando erro"* é muito vago. Você poderia [edit] a pergunta, detalhando o erro, quais dados você tentou inserir, qual deveria ser o resultado, etc. Veja também [ask] e como fornecer um [mcve].

Comment: a pergunta es mais clara possivel, eu quero inserir no banco e esta dando erro na linha que comentei, o resultado de querer inserir nao seria a insercao dos dados no banco? como deixar mais claro que isso? boto o erro aqui?

Comment: Erro ao inserir no banco pode ter **várias** causas. Pode ser que o valor não seja do mesmo tipo da coluna, ou esteja fora dos valores válidos, ou falta de permissão, etc etc etc. Sem mais detalhes sobre o erro (qual a mensagem?), a tabela e os dados que você está tentando inserir (`getNumConta()` retorna o que?), não temos como adivinhar o que está acontecendo. Tente se imaginar no lugar dos outros usuários do site que não conhecem seu sistema, não estão no mesmo contexto que você e a única coisa que eles têm é o que está na pergunta. Então, eu diria que sim, tem como deixar mais claro

Comment: Edite sua resposta e acrescente o _stack trace_ com o erro.

Comment: Este link contém uma explicação que pode parecer um pouco rude, mas sugiro que leia: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5484/112052

Comment: *"no such table: ContaCliente"* - a tabela não existe (ou o usuário não tem permissões nesta tabela). Você já verificou isso?

Comment: eu criei o banco e conectei no java, a tabela existe la

Comment: Eu não conheço SQLite tão bem assim, mas talvez isso te ajude: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14998695/java-missing-database-error